# When is the destructor of a constinit object called?

Tags: c++, destructor, c++20, initialization-order, constinit

Generally it is said that the destructors of static objects are called in the reverse order of the constructors. As I understand, constinit objects are initialized at compile time, so their destructors should be called after the destructors of "normal" static objects.

The program

```
struct A
{
  constexpr A(const char* t): t_(t) {}
  ~A() {std::cout << "~A(" << t_ << ")\n";} 
  const char* t_;
};  

static A a1("static");  

int main () {
   static constinit A a2("constinit");  
   return 0;
}
```

(using GCC 10), however, gives the output

```
~A(constinit)
~A(static)
```

i.e. the constinit object is destroyed before the "normal" static object (although it was constructed earlier). Is the "reverse order" rule no longer valid for constinit objects?

Comment: I had to revisit the standard, this is not a compiler bug, constant initialized object are destroyed as if they were dynamicaly initialized, this is specified in the standard. Violation of the reverse order rule is standard compliant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `a1` and `a2` are *constant-initialized*. The `constinit` specifier only asserts that the variable being defined is *constant-initialized*. So here `a1` is initialized before `a2` so `a2` is destroyed before `a1` as expected.

*Is the "reverse order" rule no longer valid for `constinit` objects?* The reverse order rule does not between *constant initialized* object and *dynamicaly initialized* object: even if construction of constant initialized object happens before construction of dynamicaly initialized object, destruction of constant initialized object is sequenced as if they had been dynamicaly initialized: [[basic.start.term]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.start.term#3.sentence-3)

> If an object is initialized statically, the object is destroyed in the same order as if the object was dynamically initialized.